# Saltstack action on state change

Tags: windows, salt-stack

I have a following config for saltstack to apply a change on Windows machine:

```
---
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR:
  reg.present:
    - name:
    - vname: "Start"
    - vtype: "REG_DWORD"
    - vdata: 4
```

Is there any possibility to tell saltstack to flip the value back to 4 when someone changes it manually to different value?

Answer (score 1):

Saltstack [beacons & reactors](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/beacons/) are designed for this.

You can configure a beacon on the minion, when the value changes, it will send an event to the master; on the master side, you need to create a reactor to catch this event, and apply your salt state.

However, there are currently no such beacon for windows registry, you might have to write your own.